# Primefaces Chips Web Component

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, bean-validation

I have a CRUD and I want to change the inputTexArea:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="tags" value="#{myController.selected.tags}" />
```

To the new Primefaces **chips** component:

```
<p:chips id="tags" value="#{myController.selected.tags}" />
```

An entity class excerpt:

```
@Lob
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "tags")
private String tags;
//GETTER AND SETTER OMITTED
```

The **get** method works fine, because the tags are displayed in the field as expected:

```
public List<String> getTags() {
return Arrays.asList(tags.split(","));
}
```

But the **set** method is not, because when I click on Save, occurs an Exception:

```
public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
this.tags = String.join(",", tags);
}

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SizeValidatorForCharSequence.isValid(SizeValidatorForCharSequence.java:33)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:281)
```

Can someone help me, please ?

Thanks in advance.

ps.: I've already asked this to Primefaces team (https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=51091), and a Primefaces core developer (Thomas Andraschko) orientated me to ask Hibernate validator team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Hibernate validator is confused with your getter returning `List<String>` for a `String` field. Try this:

```
public String getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(String tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public List<String> getTagsList() {
    return Arrays.asList(tags.split(","));
}

public void setTagsList(List<String> tags) {
    this.tags = String.join(",", tags);
}
```

And then:

```
<p:chips id="tags" value="#{myController.selected.tagsList}" />
```

Comment: thank you for helping me! I've just adapted the code to avoid  NullPointerException: ```public List<String> getTagsColabList() { if (tagsColab==null) { tagsColab = ""; } return  Arrays.asList(tagsColab.split(",")); }```

Answer (score 1):

[p:chips](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/chips.xhtml) uses a list as a value, why don't you use this instead:

```
private String tags = "aaaa,bbb";

public List<String> getTags() {
    return Arrays.asList(tags.split(","));
}

public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
    this.tags = String.join(",", tags);
}
```

Comment: The `getTags()` worked fine, but as I'm using Java 7, there is no `String.join("someChar",someArray)` method available. I tried `this.tags = ("," + tags)`, but got the same `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence` exception when the `setTags(List<String> tags)` is called. Please, how can I resolve it?

Comment: I also tried with Java 8 using `String.join(",", tags)`, but got the same exception. Please, can someone give a hint ?

Comment: could you paste the rest of the lines in the exception?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have java 8 but have Apache Commons Lang library, you can use

[StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) method: 
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(tags, ",") instead of String.join(",", tags);